# Increase the ABCpdf worker processes (ABCGecko)

Tags: pdf-generation, abcpdf, worker-process

ABCpdf can spawn 10 worker processes to generate PDFs. This can be changed setting the 'HtmlProcessPoolSize' registrykey. I tried setting it to 16, but only 10 processes spawn.

This setting should be configurable through configuration settings as well, which I is more interesting in our case. It gives us more control through the application.
[ABCpdf: SetConfigSection](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xsettings/1-methods/setconfigsection.htm)

Here is my configuration (or at least part of it).

```
<configSections>
    <section name="ABCpdf9.Section" type="WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.ConfigSection, ABCpdf" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
<ABCpdf9.Section>
    <Preferences>
        <clear />
        <add key="HtmlProcessPoolSize" value="16" />
    </Preferences>
</ABCpdf9.Section>
```

But there are still only 10 workerprocesses available.

Anyone knows what I am missing?

Comment: The language used in the [docs](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/d-registrykeys.htm) when describing this registry setting is: `If your application does not use multiple threads to perform HTML rendering, you can **reduce** this value to save system resources.` The specific word **reduce** might mean that it cannot be increased above the default.

Comment: That is worth investigating. Didn't pay attention to the detail in the text. Will let you know how this turned out.